# DDD\CQRS\ES Aggregate rehydration

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

When command emits more than one event, how to ensure correct rehydration. what is correct way mark many events as atomic change

Answer (score 0):

The rehydration is complete, when all available events are applied. Though, when your command emits multiple events, you just have to ensure that those events get persisted together in an atomic operation.

Example:

Current Event Stream:

```
1. MyEvent1
```

Then execute a command that emits multiple events:

```
MyCommand emits ->
  MyEvent1
  MyEvent2
```

These Events will get appended to the Event Stream as an atomic operation.

New Event Stream:

```
1. MyEvent1
2. MyEvent1
3. MyEvent2
```

Now, when rehydrating the Aggregate, you just read the entire Event Stream til the end, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

> When command emits more than one event, how to ensure correct rehydration. what is correct way mark many events as atomic change

Typically

- Your domain logic returns a *sequence* of events.
- You atomically write the entire sequence into the event history
- When reconstituting, you use the event history

Note that the second step implies that your durable event storage will support the atomic write of an event sequence.

Note: we don't usually rely on the *broadcast* mechanism when reconstituting the state of our domain model, but instead use the history.

In the CQRS world, that would include creating the read model by loading the history, and then playing the events in the fixed order in which they were written.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your underlying storage. A common way to implement atomic writes for persistent storage that does not support transactions is to create a batch of events and write that as a single operation.

When rehydrating the events you can flatten the batches to a flat sequence/stream of events to build your current state. During rehydration you really care about all events, since you will always apply the next command on fully hydrated current state. Thus, there is no point in keeping the batches at that point.

There are a number of solutions out there that support writing/rehydration of state like this if you don't feel like building your own.

- Event store (https://eventstore.com)
- Axon server (https://axoniq.io)
- Serialized (https://serialized.io) *for full disclosure - this is our product*

Good luck